# Do people want the meta posts to appear in the chat feed?

Tags: discussion, chat, meta

Now that the meta site has calmed down a bit, do people want the feed of new posts to automatically appear in our chat room?

I know we do it on [cogsi.se] and it's not a bad way to keep people informed of meta, as intial site has been thrashed out and  enthusiam levels out.

Comment: I think it should be in ticker feed rather then message feed. Mostly in other SE chatrooms meta question is used as a ticker feed and main site question as message feed and its look ideal to me.

Comment: @AnkitSharma interesting, that's the exact opposite of what we do on Mi Yodeya, and several other sites also feed meta to chat (though they may have gotten it from us on MY).  Is there really a norm?

Comment: @MonicaCellio can you see if it's the right link? I posted a test Q on meta and it hasn't come through.. hm

Comment: @AnkitSharma not a ticker feed, that's for bigger sites like [smo] we won't have many meta posts

Comment: Give it time; the feed takes anywhere from 10 minutes to an hour or more.  (I haven't set these up before, so I could look at the URL but I'm not sure I know more than you do on this. :-) )

Comment: @MonicaCellio I might look at your other chat room feed url brb

Answer (score 4):

Folks that hang out in chat are usually very enthused about the site and how it works, it's definitely a good idea to make sure new meta posts get in front of them - we want consensus on discussions after all.

You could also *try* for a short time a feed of new questions on the main site, but that might get to be too noisy after our content gets picked up and indexed properly by search engines, at least I hope it does :)

But yeah - definitely keep the meta feed as long as folks don't mind it too much. I'm actually wondering if we shouldn't set up that feed by default for new sites when we create the chat room, since it's usually a week before anyone *but* us can touch feeds.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think it is **very** helpful for meta questions to appear in the chat feed.

Particularly now that we're in public beta, we will likely see the frequency of meta discussion drop off.

Keeping users engaged in meta is very important for a site's health... and potentially difficult to accomplish.  When the activity is infrequent, any reminder to get people to check out the latest in meta is very helpful.

I doubt the volume will be enough to disrupt chat, but if for some reason it does become a problem, we can always reevaluate.

Comment: Erm do I go ahead and implement it on a consensus of two ?? lol

Comment: I'm not sure I see any harm in implementing it now.  If people complain, I'd suggest you might want to be responsive to that, since two really doesn't qualify as a consensus ;)

Comment: If they complain, I'll blame you hahahahhahaha

Comment: Fair enough! :)

Comment: can you check that I added the url correctly??? O<O O>O (that's my looks L looks R)

Comment: It looks right to me, but I've never actually tried that before.  I guess we'll find out the next time someone posts a Q in meta :)

Comment: Em, can you think of a question to ask... O<O O>O hehehhe

Comment: omg as long as it's not the feed to a porn site! LOL

Comment: @Skippy rite link is http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/feeds